# Append a new Node (String) to XML with prefix

Tags: xml, vb.net, prefix

I've working a bit with XMLs and got stuck with the following. I have the following XML:

```
<cfdi:Receit xmlns:xsi="http://..." xmlns:cfdi="http://..." Certificate="20001000000200001437">
     <cfdi:From nombre="My Name">
          <cfdi:Country Country="USA"/>
     </cfdi:From>
     <cfdi:To name="Receptor Name">
          <cfdi:Country Country="UK"/>
     </cfdi:Receptor>
</cfdi:Receit>
```

I've been trying to insert a new node "Export", that I have saved up in a string, to the Root of this XML which should make it look like this

```
<cfdi:Receit xmlns:xsi="http://..." xmlns:cfdi="http://..." Certificate="20001000000200001437">
     <cfdi:From nombre="My Name">
          <cfdi:Country Country="USA"/>
     </cfdi:From>
     <cfdi:To name="Receptor Name">
          <cfdi:Country Country="UK"/>
     </cfdi:Receptor>

     <cfdi:Export>
          <tfd:ExportData xmlns:tfd="http://..." xmlns:xsi="http://..." exportCertificate="0001110111010110" ExportQuantity="12,255"/>
     </cfdi:Export>

</cfdi:Receit>
```

Is there a simple way of just inserting the node as a string to the root of the original XML? I´ve been trying with many ways, one being that I just insert the string but when opened by navigator it does not seem to form part of the XML as a node. 
I've tried the example below, but they all have a an issue with the prefix "cfdi" needed in the new node.

```
Dim xdOriginal As New XDocument = "Original XML"
Dim NewNode As String = <cfdi:Export> <tfd:ExportData xmlns:tfd="http://..." xmlns:xsi="http://..." exportCertificate="0001110111010110" ExportQuantity="12,255"/> </cfdi:Export>


Dim xDoc As New XElement(XElement.Parse(NewNode)) ' Error Here

xdOriginal.Root.Add(xDoc)
```

Comment: Is the namespace in the beginning of the xmldoc above valid, i.e. can you navigate there.  If not, it will not parse and will fail.  remove it as a test to see if your code works.  Also remember that Visual Studio use the MSXML1.1 parser, I think so it does not support everything.

Comment: hi, yes the namespace is valid and I need the Node as it is, but I'll try it without the namespace.

Comment: I had issues with Microsoft Dynamics XML referring to "non-existant" NS that caused C# to "get upset"...  Just eliminate (or start simple), until it works (confirm your code), then put back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XNamespace` variable to supply namespace prefix that is declared outside scope of parsed XML string :

```
Dim xdOriginal As New XDocument = "Original XML"

Dim cfdi As XNamespace = "cfdi namespace URI here"
Dim newNodeContent = <tfd:ExportData xmlns:tfd="http://..." xmlns:xsi="http://..." exportCertificate="0001110111010110" ExportQuantity="12,255"/>
'use XNamespace variable to add prefix to <Export> element :'
Dim newNode = New XElement(cfdi + "Export", newNodeContent)
xdOriginal.Root.Add(newNode)
```